# what are Selenium IDE "Arguments"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm new to Selenium IDE, I'm reading their official docs, under API Reference section.
I understand the purpose of Commands, they are what I see in the recorded scripts.
But what are Arguments, what are they for, where are they used? There is no general description in the docs, only the list of them.
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are the "things" you pass to commands. If you look on the [commands page](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands), you will see that practically all commands have one or more arguments.

For example, the [click](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands#click) command.

[image: click]

The argument in this case is a locator... CSS selector, ID, XPath, etc.